# How to synchronize data flow between Node.js processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, synchronization

In my application, I need to read data from one socket, do some processing, write it to file, and send it to another socket. The order of the data is important and must be maintained without dropping any of it.

I'm using domains and clustering combined for error handling. A domain will catch the error, exit the current process, and fork a new one. It is possible to have multiple processes running concurrently for load balancing.

I don't believe I have any guarantee or control over how the data is handled between the processes. So, how can I maintain the order of the data flowing as a whole, without losing any should a process catch an exception and exit?

*UPDATE:*
Example problem: There is a stream of data coming in on a socket. Two concurrent processes each read a chunk of that stream. By random selection, each process has a chance to write its chunk to file. By random selection, each process then has a chance to send its chunk to another socket. There is only one shared incoming socket, one shared file, and one shared outgoing socket. I need to guarantee the order of the data coming in remains the same going to file and out the other socket.

Comment: You are worried about getting an orphaned 'transaction' should the cluster die? Trying to understand the problem a little better.

Comment: That's one of the issues, which I think could be solved by the same solution as keeping the "transactions" in order between parallel processes.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem, but what I understand is that you need to serially process the data coming in. Typically if I need to coordinate flow throw multiple processes I will have work queue that exists outside of the process. Redis is my solution usually. http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

Comment: Added an example problem to help illustrate the issue. Hope it helps.